# Magento Development IDE

Tags: magento, ide, magento-1.7, phpstorm, magento-1.6

¿Which is the best IDE for **Magento** professional development: **NetBeans**, **ZendStudio**, **PhpStorm**, etc.?

> I really need know which one have the best performance during
>   development and testing, the features that any IDE can bring me.

any answer will be wellcome.

Excuse my english, 
Mexican Boy!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PHPStorm is the best in my opinion (however NetBeans also works good with Magento, probably Eclipse and ZendStudio work good. but have no experience with them).

PHPStorm

- Code Completion
- Strong integration with Git, SVN and Mercurial
- Remote Deployment and Remote comparison
- PHPUnit Integration
- Portability (Windows, Mac OS and Linux) 
  and many more useful features

But PHPStorm becomes really powerful IDE for Magento with the help of [Magicento plugin](http://magicento.com/)

Magicento is a free PHPStorm plugin for Magento developers. Features include:
Goto for factories and template paths, autocomplete for factories, xml files and class names, documentation for xml nodes, evaluation of PHP code inside Magento environment, and much more to come!

Comment: Thanks Segei! I will try this IDE.

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/) is the best free IDE for php in my opinion (once your computer have 500mb to 1gb of free memory)

Answer (score 0):

i have been using Eclipse with pdt plugin download from here [zend eclipse ptd](http://www.zend.com/en/company/community/pdt/downloads)

if you develop module than this is right IDE